# PreparedStatement ignores parameters in the query: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I use java and jdbc driver (java.sql), and I got this piece of code:

```
String clinetIP = "220.181.108.89";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM `as` WHERE `as`.ip_range LIKE '%?%'";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, clinetIP);
```

I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

while executing statement.setString(1, clinetIP).

Why is that? doesn't statement.setxxx looks for question marks in the statement string? I have used one question mark in the statement, but it seems to be ignored!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM `as` WHERE `as`.ip_range LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, "%" + clientIP + "%");
```

Answer (score 1):

Right way is:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM `as` WHERE `as`.ip_range LIKE ?";
statement.setString(1, "%" + clinetIP + "%");
```

Parameters binding doesn't work inside a literal!